# Image loads on desktop but won't load when the website is pushed onto github/netlify

Tags: html, css

I've been coding this website on my mac, and so when I copy the full project path from atom into chrome, the image loads up fine. However, after pushing the exact same thing to github and subsequently publishing the github push onto netlify - the image won't load. How would I be able to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <img src="./images/vice-logoFlag1.png" width="50" height="50">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/Users/nixon/Documents/Website Development/Website 1 Project/home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Gang Database
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">The Ballas</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">The Families</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Los Santos Vagos</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Varrios Los Aztecas</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Marabunta Grande</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="logout" type="submit">Log out</button>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <body>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Referencing this line:
<img src="/Users/nixon/Documents/GitHub/sid-vice-website/images/vice-logoFlag1.png" width="50" height="50">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the image will depend on the location of it. Try
`<img src=". /images/vice-logoFlag1.png" width="50" height="50">`
if your image is located inside a folder named images inside your project

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't able to resolve the issue. The image is still not loading in - here's the text (I tried it with a space between the . and / aswell, to no avail): 
<img src="./images/vice-logoFlag1.png" width="50" height="50">

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your file structure, and point where your image is stored ? That way I can help you find the right path to your image

Comment: Another option is to use an external image storage where you can store your image, so you can point your url to that image. Check cloudinary for that

Answer (score 2):

When refrencing to external sources (within your website) it shuold be reletive to the page you're on.
For example in the root folder you have the index.html and one folder named img with logo.png. If you want to display that image you would want to point to img/logo.png.

Edit, addition:
It looks like you're refrencing to a file stored locally on your computer. But when viewing something local the root would be somewhere esle compaerd to the root folder if you upload on github.